# checking restful features of the action in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

when drawing restful routes in ruby on rails you specify

1. if a controller action applies to a member or collection and
2. what http verb is used. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

How can I check 1 from within the controller instance?
(The HTTP verb can be checked via `request.method`)

The ugly hack is to check if the named route exists with singular or plural, but the route can have alternative name.

Yet another is to check for the request param used for identifying the member, but collection routes could have the same (optional) param.

Answer (score 0):

If the route is following restful conventions, then running `rake routes`should give you the answers you are looking for.

You will see what http verb is expected (answer to 2) and the path should answer your 1) question. For a member action, you need the ID, so typically the path contains the id

This route configuration:

```
resources :photos do
  member do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

will give you the path `photos/:id/preview` -> ment to preview a single photo

And the route configuration:

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    get 'preview'
  end
end
```

will give you the path `photos/preview`  -> ment to preview a list of photos

If you need to get this information from within the code of an action:

- Inspect the params[:id] to distinguish the intent. If it is for a member, that value will be not nil.

Comment: yes, need to get this information from within the code of an action and your solution is not safe enough as I already pointed out in my question. thx anyway

Comment: Could you be more specific about your intent and routes?
How is it possible to have an optional :id in a restful route meant for collections?

Comment: GET /products?id=2&evil_hackers_name=me

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Journey gem for such a method? Assuming 3.2, that would have it, if anywhere, rather than request param. By then it's too late isn't it?

Comment: sorry don't see how request param helps. also journey doesn't even have readme, any specific hints where to look? thx

Comment: That is what I meant, is that by the time `request` is created, you are passed the 'identification of Member or Collection' stage. Journey is an Object that may contain whether it's a member or not, dunno yet. Honestly though, if it's RESTful, you either have params or you don't. If it's super sensitive, strip the params even with `params = ''` I so much prefer member and scoping from current_user or something like that, when possible. I'm sure you know that, but it's good for google too. :-)